# Custom Polar Chart with gridlines D3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have to plot a custom polar chart in which the radius of the circles vary and the grid lines are created at 30 degrees separation.Below is my code which plots the circle. The problem is that I am not able to plot the gridlines on the svg. The gridlines takes values from the list **grid** and it has values in x1,y1,x2,y2 format. Any idea why is it not plotting the gridline?
[The image shows that it is taking only a single value from the list and appending it in the variables x1,y1,x2,y2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wUjA.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="circles"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var circleRadii = [100,90,80,70,60,50,40,30,20];
    var min_radii = d3.min(circleRadii);
    var max_radii = d3.max(circleRadii);
    var theta_range = d3.range(0,360,30);
    document.write(theta_range);


    //set the svg container size
    width = 750;
    height =  750;
    grid = [395,375,392.32,385,385,392.32,375,395,365,392.32,357.68,385,355,375,357.68,365,365,357.68,375,355,385,357.68,392.32,365,395,375]

    var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                        .attr("width",width)
                                        .attr("height",height);

    var circles = svgContainer.selectAll("circle")
                              .data(circleRadii)
                              .enter()
                              .append("circle")

    var circleAttributes = circles
                          .attr("cx",width/2)
                          .attr("cy",height/2)
                          .attr("r", function (d) { return d; })
                          .style("stroke","gray")
                          .style("fill","white"); 


    var gridlines  = svgContainer.append("gridline")
                    .data(grid)
                    .enter().append("gridline")
                    .attr("x1",function(d){return d;})
                    .attr("y1",function(d){return d;})
                    .attr("x2",function(d){return d;})
                    .attr("y2",function(d){return d;})
                    .attr("stroke", "black")
                    .attr("stroke-width", 2);     
console.log(gridlines);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are no `grid` elements in SVG. Use `line` or `path`.

Comment: grid is basically the array which has the values for x1,y1,x2,y2.And I don't think it makes any difference whether we use grid or lines.I mean the code

`var lines  = svgContainer.append("line")
                    .attr("x1",365)
                    .attr("y1",453)
                    .attr("x2",363)
                    .attr("y2",543)
                    .attr("stroke", "black")
                    .attr("stroke-width", 2);`
will work properly

Comment: @LarsKotthoff grid is basically the array which has the values for x1,y1,x2,y2.And I don't think it makes any difference whether we use grid or lines.I mean the code

`var lines  = svgContainer.append("line").attr("x1",365).attr("y1",453).attr("x2",363).attr("y2",543).attr("stroke", "black").attr("stroke-width",2);`
will work properly

Comment: You picture of dom elements and code completely differ. Your code produce just `<line></line>` with error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function `

Comment: @AntoJurković check it now. Sorry for the wrong snippet. :)

Comment: OK, it's different now but as Lars mentioned, there is no `gridline` element in svg. Anyway, each gridline element has two points with the same data. Maybe this example could help: [D3.JS - how do I add gridlines to my pie chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177974/d3-js-how-do-i-add-gridlines-to-my-pie-chart)

Comment: I tried. Not working.